# Delphi XE2: Why FireMonkey apps are HD?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

According to release notes of Delphi XE2.  FireMonkey may create HD application.  HD stands for High Definition.  Why HD?  Can't VCL application create HD apps as FireMonkey?

Comment: @David: In the File -> New menu, it is called "FireMonkey HD project".

Comment: I think it's a reference to iOS, the pre-iphone 4 devices have a lower resolution than the iphone4 and the ipad. The higher resolution is called `HD` in apple-speak. It's a hint that firemonkey allows you to write applications for the iOS 4+ and not just iOS 3.

Comment: The higher resolution display is actually called "Retina" in Apple speak.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the [documentation on Firemonkey](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Application_Platform), from it you can see several features.

Compare normal TV to HD TV.  Is like comparing the VCL to what Firemonkey can do.
It's a Marketing term that I suspect will catch on as it, does highlight the power.

HD Applications refer many of the features of Firemonkey but the following stand out.

- 2D Applications (VCL can do this)
- 3D Applications (VCL can not do this)
- Powerful Vector engine (VCL can not do this)
- Leverages the GPU  (Most of VCL does not do this)

The first paragraph of this above Doc page sums it up best.

> FireMonkey leverages the graphics processing unit (GPU) in modern
>   desktop and mobile devices to create visually engaging applications on
>   multiple platforms, targeting the entire range from the personal to
>   the enterprise

I Suspect more and more demo videos will appear over the next few weeks but the difference is significant when compared to the VCL.

Answer (score 13):

"HD" is really is just a marketing alias for "2D", because they wanted to convey something more than what the VCL provides.

And it does provide more, primarily because it is vector-based while the VCL is raster-based.

Comment: That is, 2D + 3D = HD ? Nice catch!

Answer (score 8):

All coordinates are in floating point precision while in the Standard VCL they are integer values. It perfectly makes sense: the definition is higher, so it's HD...as simple as that

In standard VCL app you can also have HD graphics but not without the use of a third-part graphic library such as Gdi+ or GLScene.

Comment: Hmmm... it actually uses Single, so its **precision** is lower than that of Integer. <g> It is nice to be able to have sub pixel resolution, as that scales easier, but otherwise, it is not higher D than anything else.